# Disable swipe to dismiss in swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

Im using webview that inside it there is touchmove intraction.
The problem is, that when the event runing (user touchmove) the view itself moves too.
So i figure its with the swipe to dismiss.
However, when the page in webview have scroll (large height) so the swipe to dismiss doesn't active
There is a way to prevent only the web view from swipe navigation?
Thanks and sorry for bad english

Comment: .interactiveDismissDisabled()

Comment: Thanks for answer but still screen move when touchmove event(its just not closing with the swipe)

Comment: Post some code.